# Virtualbox won't display Samsung SmartTV Emulator - instead it shows a grey screen

Tags: sdk, virtualbox, emulation, samsung-smart-tv

i got some problems with the Samsung Smart TV SDK Emulator for VirtualBox.

I have installed the VirtualBox-Version 4.2.16 and when I try to load the 2014_Smart_TV_Emulator_5_1.ova, it always shows after the boot logo , a grey screen. I already used Google to search the problem but could not find anything.

Can some help me or has the same problem to face with the emulator ?

Thanks 
Regards
Kami

Comment: can u please post screen shot

Comment: I cant post an image, but you see the screen was just grey.. it displayed nothing. I think the whole  virtual machine just hang up..

Comment: thats y i want to see the screen shot as it may be app launch page and you have to launch app thorugh eclipse but i can only help you when i will be able to see the screen shot

Comment: Hi @abhi, here are the images: [link](http://picload.org/image/iogrwgl/applincesettings.jpg) , [link](http://picload.org/image/iogrwgp/deactivatedio-apic.jpg) , [link](http://picload.org/image/iogrwdr/greyscreen.jpg)  . .. as you see the first picture display what settings I used, the second picture show that i deactivated IO-APIC because i don't have Visualization activated, there is no such functionality currently on my pc, the third picture shows the grey screen after booting up the VM.. Thx :)

Comment: try uninstalling and then re installing both virtual box and ova file again

Comment: Hi i tried that almost, 10 times .. it wont work, i have also tried different versions of virtual box. but same problem..